# Asterisk calls drop on sip reload when used asterisk as sip client to tollfree provider

Tags: asterisk, sip

When do sip reload from asterisk cli Everything is fine but when I make some change in sip.conf (even a small change just adding one comment statement) and then reloading causes all call drops. Even if I just do touch sip.conf ( anything that changes it's time stamp) and than reloading causes all call drops.
Note: This is happening only in case of registering asterisk to tollfree providers ( using register line in general section ). 
I am using asterisk13. 
Can anyone suggest why it's happening and what is its solution.

Answer (score 0):

Can suggest upgrade asterisk to latest availible version.

It NOT restart on reload for sure in current version.

Comment: no it doesn't restart asterisk on reload, the only thing that is happening is when I do sip  show registry the provider is unregistered and then gets registered again and due to this small delay all calls get drop. any suggestion to increase that re-register time. Or any config. that stop it from re-register